# create a dynamic html file and execute it in google apps script

Tags: javascript, excel, google-apps-script, vba

I'm trying to migrate various Excel applications to Google Apps. These generate html and javaScript based on various excel data and parameters to create a local html file which is then opened by a browser.

I know it's a long shot, but can anyone think of a way to mimic this behavior in Google Apps Script? Namely - create a file on the client and fetch it up in a browser session.

[Here's an example of the type of application I mean](http://ramblings.mcpher.com/Home/excelquirks/d3/sankey)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [DocsListApp.createFile](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/class_docslist#createFile) to create new HTML files on the user's Google Drive, but I don't believe you can serve the HTML from Drive directly. Alternatively you can use the SitesApp to create a new page on a Google Site with the HTML you want, using [Site.addWebPage](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/class_site#createWebPage). Finally, you may want to look into the widgets available in UiApp or the UI Builder, to see if you can use those instead of custom HTML.

Comment: Eric- thanks for the idea. If Google drive could serve html it would certainly solve a few other problems too. These html files use a lot of javaScript and external APIs so I cant do it on a site (javascript restrictions). I'll mull the idea to see if it could somehow mashed around as input to a gadget. Bruce

Comment: This is now much more possible using the new google Apps script htmlService. http://excelramblings.blogspot.co.uk/2012/07/using-google-apps-script-as-rest-server.html

Answer (score 0):

Just saw this:

https://googledrive.com/host/0B716ywBKT84AMXBENXlnYmJISlE/GoogleDriveHosting.html

HTML files uploaded to Public Google Drive folder are served as HTML, link is available through "Preview" button.

So far it doesn't work with Google Drive files simply moved to that folder but perhaps would work with files created there via createFile script.